# How to configure CRSF with Spring Boot and Angular 7

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, csrf

I'm flowing with Spring Boot and Angular article from [Spring.io sight](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii). Section The Login Page, **part with adding logout**. I have problem with configuring CRSF. They write this

> The last choice is the best because Angular has built in support for CSRF (which it calls "XSRF") based on cookies.

but it seems that it is not the case in Angular 7 (in the article they use angular 4). Because when I have put a breakpoint in CsrfFilter, method doFilterInternal returns me a null CRSF token and browser response is

```
{"timestamp":"2019-04-30T08:15:16.593+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/api/logout"}
```

I tried to add

```
HttpXsrfTokenExtractor
```

for Angular part of application and then when sending a request set a X-XSRF-TOKEN like so

```
const token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
    this.httpClient.post('api/logout', {}, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)}).pipe(finalize(() => {
      this.userService.user.authenticated = false;
      this.userService.user.name = '';
      this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
    })).subscribe();
```

But i get this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:241)
    at http.js:212
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init (http.js:212)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:277)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1529)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at subscribeTo.js:21
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
```

and I don't really understated it.

I expect that I can logout and the CsrfFilter.class will show me the actual CSRF token.

Comment: Looks like JavaScript, not Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what's was going on.
For development purposes I set in Angualar app proxy.conf.json that all my request should be proxied to Spring Boot app, because I develop both apps separately, due to dynamic reload content in Angualr app, but in the end I want one app. With maven-fronten-plugin i build the Angual app and copy dist folder to static content in Spring Boot. The proxy.conf.json was

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I didn't know that I can just put "/**" to proxy all my calls. So in the Spring Boot app, in application properties I set

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

It seems that this configuration some how break normal flow. So I removed the context-path from Spring Boot app and changed proxy config for Angular app. Now all is working fine.